# The class name gets scrambled when passing to call_user_func

Tags: php, yii, php-5.3

I have developed my website locally with PHP 5.3 and everything works fine.
When uploading the project to my webserver, some strange behaviour has been happening.

Basically, the error is:

```
include(/home2/server/public_html/pontai/frontend/config/../../frontend/controllers/api/v1/sag8egnqhnzijhv.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I absolutely do not have the file "ag8egnqhnzijhv.php" in my project, so I don't know where php is taking this from.

My classes have namespaces, so I do the following:

```
$namespace=str_replace('\\','.',ltrim($className,'\\'));
if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false)
include($path.'.php');
```

The error is being thrown in this last line 'include'

Stacktrace shows error coming from here:

```
call_user_func(array($this->resource_class, 'view'), $this->getParams('GET'));
```

Has anyone ever seen that?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit further on that? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, can you to provide the code for `getPathOfAlias`? There's not enough information in this question to figure it out.

Comment: I've just recently run in to this too. Have you found out what is causing it?